# Error when trying to update Item Class and Posting Class using Import Scenario Stock Items Screen

Tags: acumatica

When I try to update Posting Class and Item Class Field on IN202500 screen. I got this error: "Please confirm if you want to update current Item settings with the Inventory Class defaults. Original settings will be preserved otherwise.". It's fine to change in manual but got error while using import scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating new inventory items, just move Item class and Posting class to the top below inventoryid (it doesn't pop the question if not overwriting).  Otherwise, try using 'Dialog Answer' in Field/Action Name and 'Yes' in Source Field/Value.